# Check if information from database is blank

Tags: php

I need to check if status A and B  is blank or 0, but my blank doesnt work, Any suggestions?

```
 $sta = db2_result($queryexe, 'STATUSA');
 $stb = db2_result($queryexe, 'STATUSB');


 if ($sta=="0" OR $sta=="" AND $stb=="0" OR $stb=="")
```

Comment: You need to learn about [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php): you're mixing `and` and `or` without `()` to enforce the evaluation order, and the built-in precedence is executing that differently than you think it should be.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [empty](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.empty.php) function which consider 0, "0", null... as empty values :

```
if (empty($sta) && empty($stb)) {
```

If you want to stick with your logic, consider to separate the if statements in two parts :

```
if (
    ($sta=="0" OR $sta=="")
    AND
    ($stb=="0" OR $stb=="")
) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (($sta=="0" OR $sta=="") AND ($stb=="0" OR $stb==""))
```

2+3*4 is not the same as (2+3)*4. The same is with OR and AND